# Failed To Convert Parameter Value From A String To A Int32

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am currently trying to complete a transaction for a web based app, however;

> Failed To Convert Parameter Value From A String To A Int32

Here is copy of the function.

```
public static void completeTransaction(string storeCode, string employeeId, DateTime Date, string itemListNoId)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ; Initial Catalog =Business ; Integrated Security = true;"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.completeTransaction", conn))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@storeCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = storeCode;
            command.Parameters.Add("@employeeId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = employeeId;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date;
            command.Parameters.Add("@itemListNoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = itemListNoId;
            conn.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

My SQL Server table contains the following tables and types

```
storeCode INT
employee INT
Date DATETIME
itemListNoId INT
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to parse the string to Int.32 DataType

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# SQL Server 2008" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive the problem is in your first paramter (storeCode). You're trying to send a string as an int paramter.

That line should read like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@storeCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(storeCode);
```

There's one more suspicious thing: the parameter's name is storeCode, which implies a varchar column. What's the value you're trying to pass as a storeCode? Are you sure it's an int?

Comment: it appears its because I was referencing the employees name instead of their their ID.

Answer (score 1):

One of the inputs is a string, check the declarations for:

```
storeCode
employeeId
itemListNoId
```

I imagine `storeCode` is a string.  You can fix this by parsing it as an `Int`:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@storeCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(storeCode);
```

However this will cause problems if `storeCode` is ever no a parasable `Int`.

Comment: it appears its because I was referencing the employees name instead of their their ID.

Comment: Maybe off topic, but still: your parameters sholdn't be strings if you're using them for passing int values.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you change the type of the parameters in the method.

to

```
public static void completeTransaction(int storeCode, int employeeId, DateTime Date, string itemListNoId)
```

and convert the strings before passing the values to the method.