# Passing INT to stored procedure fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, int

I'm trying to pass a `CommandArgument` as `int` to my stored procedure, but I get:

> *Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32*

Even when it is converted before I pass it...

C# Code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "deleteProd";
int delprodID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

Response.Write(delprodID);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prodID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = delprodID;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

sqlTools.cmdToNonQuery(cmd)
```

My `Response.Write` shows that I've got the right ID in `delprodID`.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.deleteProd @prodID int
AS
IF @prodID > 0
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM products WHERE prodID = @prodID
END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099141/failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a-string-to-a-int32-while-executing-store

Comment: What does `cmdToNonQuery` do?  Could it be munging the command parameters?

Comment: Use Sql Server Profiler and track what goes to DataBase.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem 3 months ago and couldn't explain what was going on. Somehow, you must explicitly declare parameter, set it and then add it to the Parameters property. It was only happening on SQL Server, not on Access for instance. I know that this is basically the same code but this worked for me, don't ask me why:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@prodID", SqlDbType.Int);
param.Value = delprodID;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)
It will greatly simplify things.

```
cmd.CommandText = "deleteProd";
int delprodID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
Response.Write(delprodID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodID", delprodID);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlTools.cmdToNonQuery(cmd)
```