# Failed to convert parameter value from a DataRowView to a Int32

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ado.net

I'm inserting records and one of my object is combobox. The combox is connected to the table. When i'm inserting this error appear:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a DataRowView to a Int32

My code:

```
cn.Open();

SqlCommand Insert = new SqlCommand();
Insert.Connection = cn;
Insert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Ticket  VALUES (CustomerID, Date, Store, Amount, NoStub) ";

Insert.Parameters.Add("CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cboName.SelectedValue;
Insert.Parameters.Add("Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpDate.Value.Date.ToString();
Insert.Parameters.Add("Store", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStore.Text;
Insert.Parameters.Add("Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtAmount.Text;
Insert.Parameters.Add("NoStub", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtStub.Text;

Insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

cn.Close();
```

Comment: add some what-you-have-tried code so you can expect quicker answers rather sounding too generic

Comment: Could you solve the issue? In case an you solved it and in case one of the answers was the one that helped you to solve the issue it would be good to accept it as answer. If you still have trouble it would help that you tell where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675857/failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a-string-to-a-int32) code:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(storeCode);
```

or use
`int.parse` for cboName.

Comment: Or just `Int32.Parse(storeCode)`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the following and let the Server resolve the data type

```
cn.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.Connection = cn;
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Ticket(CustomerID, Date, Store, Amount, NoStub)  
                       VALUES (@CustomerID, @Date, @Store, @Amount, @NoStub) ";
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", cboName.SelectedValue);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dtpDate.Value.Date.ToString());
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Store", txtStore.Text);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", txtAmount.Text);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoStub", txtStub.Text);
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```